# Proper way to authenticate with a backend server

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server), in order to authenticate with a backend server I have to :

- send the user's ID token to my server using HTTPS.
- verify the integrity of the ID token and retrieve the user's ID from the sub claim of the ID token.

This work quite well, but how to do if I have to authenticate all the request to the server ?

Should I store the idToken (on a private sharred preferences) and verify it each time server side ? Since the idToken have a validity date, the client must be able to regenerate it when it has expired.

Or on the first connection, should I return a single id (without validity date) to the user which will allow him to communicate with the server (seems less secure) ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, just wanted to understand if the token that you are retrieving from GoogleSignInOptions is a JWT right? This token has a validity of just 1 hour. Can you please help me understand how to renew this token? I get same JWT from GSO, even though it is expired

Comment: Yes, this is a JWT. You have to call `silentSignIn` before each API call. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37387199/3580745)

Comment: When ever i call silentSignIn after an hour I still get the same old token. Here is my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363213/google-always-returns-expired-id-tokenjwt

Answer (score 2):

The token should be verify with every request to the server it's like a key for each request. This key is not valid for a long time period so you have normally a refresh token if you want the "session" to be persistent. If you don't have it you will need to authenticate again every time the validity period of the token is expired.

So yes you should store the token in the client side. The best practice is to have a really short validity period to be sure that if the token is compromise the attacker will have a short time to do malicious thing.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I do not have a refresh token, so I will to authenticate each time it expired.

Answer (score 1):

I foud a technical answer (@EmCode's answer is correct) in the doc of the `silentSignIn()` method. (Here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#public-methods)).

> The GoogleSignInResult will possibly contain an ID token which may be used to authenticate and identify sessions that you establish with your application servers. If you use the ID token expiry time to determine your session lifetime, you should retrieve a refreshed ID token, by calling silentSignIn prior to each API call to your application server.

Answer (score 0):

See if this makes sense:

> *This work quite well, but how to do if I have to authenticate all the request to the server ?*

I think the purpose of google sign-in is to authenticate users by their google credentials. It is not really for authenticating all your client requests against your own server. What will happens between your server and google should be only user token validation. Once the token is validated fine, the subsequent C/S data exchange can use authentication of your choice, and no need to bother google each time or care about the token validity.

> *If you use the ID token expiry time to determine your session lifetime, you should retrieve a refreshed ID token, by calling
>   silentSignIn prior to each API call to your application server.*

Yes, if sessions are used your application and you want the token to define validity, then you need to bother Google all the time.

Answer (score -1):

The Proper way to authenticate with a backend server is retrofit use this lib this is very fast to fetch data or upload data on beckend server.

Comment: Retrofit is an http client (and I already use it). This does not answer my question