# Google always returns expired id token(JWT)

Tags: android, google-oauth

According to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#constant-summary

> If you use the ID token expiry time to determine your session lifetime, you should retrieve a refreshed ID token, by calling silentSignIn prior to each API call to your application server.

I am trying to get a new token by calling silentSignIn. But, I always get the same expired ID token. Can some one please help me in pointing out the right documentation that shows how to force refresh to get a new token. My code is nothing special. It's almost the same as what we have in google's sample.

```
private void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and
    // basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            //.requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
            .requestIdToken(SERVER_ID)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to GoogleSignIn.API and the options above.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

I build my API as above and when user clicks on login with google button I perform the following action

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone())
        {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Timber.d("Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            Timber.d("Checking if user has already given access to this app on an other device.");
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult)
                {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
```

handleSignInResult method would get the id token as

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
Timber.d(acct.getIdToken());
```

**EDIT 1**

I have another related question.

After I revoked the permission from https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/permissions I was still able to retrieve the ID token(JWT). Let's assume that this token is cached and Android play services is providing it from a local copy. After the token expires(60 mins) play service should contact Google's service to get the latest status. But, I don't see this happening. In fact, another strange thing that I have noticed is when I call silentSignIn() after like a day or so, I get a new token with out user's consent. Can some one please test this use case and let me know the output.

How can I make sure user's are requested to give permission again when they have revoked it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how OptionalPendingResult works, but have you tried the guide here? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow (up to date as of May 17, 2016).  This guide uses `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, which is how I implemented mine and it retrieves a non-expired token.

Comment: Oh! i forgot to add startActivityForResult() part. I tried with this as well. but there was no change in the result. How did you get non-expired token? google only gives a 1 hour token. did you decode the JWT with something similar to https://jwt.io/ ? what is the "exp" epoch value?

Comment: I used the Google Token Endpoint described here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-authI will write this up as a solution.

Comment: can you please help me with retrying to generate another token after 1 hour and check it at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=blah_blah

Comment: Also within this 1 hour duration of generating the token, can you try to revoke access for this application? what do you see?

Comment: Are you using the instructions here to revoke access? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect#disconnect_accounts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113073/discussion-between-killiam-and-rakesh-kashyap).

Comment: Can you try obtaining another token and wait an hour and let me know what you see? Also, try hitting the endpoint with the token immediately after obtaining the token, then hitting the endpoint with the token after an hour as well.

Comment: i am on the chat already... https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect#disconnect_accounts provides us a way to revoke access from the application. But user can also revoke access from google's application console. that's https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/permissions

Comment: I have the same problem. It happen on the just one phone and one account. But also several of my app users reported it already. It looks like bug on Google side, it works normally for most of users. I didn't found the solution how to force refresh token. I tried also clear data for Play Store and Play Services and it doesn't help.

Comment: @rakeshkashyap Did you able to resolve the issue? I am stuck in the exactly same problem. Google is returning same Id token to me when i do the sign through google signin Intent. When i pass the id token to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XXXX" it gave "error_description": "Invalid Value". Please share your final solution.

Comment: @Klone Where is your chat discussion? I am getting page not found.

Comment: Check if the date on problematic devices is set correctly.

Comment: I've just run into the same issue, Google returning what seems to be an expired token. Turned out the android device (which was actually an emulator) system time was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `startActivityForResult()`, then handle the sign-in result in `onActivityResult()`, as explained here [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow). Then, to verify the authenticity of the token, please see Google's guide for Google Sign-In for Android on how to [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint).

A simple way is to pass the token to the Google tokeninfo endpoint
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123` where XYZ123 is your token.